# fastest way to search text value for words in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, search

I have a requirement to identify keywords stored in a table column in text passed to a stord procedure, at present I'm pasing the text in as rows in a table value, however as populating the table value is hideously slow, I'm going to scrap this approach. I looked at the full text search option, however based on my very limited understanding of this, specifically:-

1. The data has to already reside in a database table column.
2. I cannot see any obvious way of using freetext or contains such that the words / expressions you are searching for can be passed into this en mass from another database table.

Can someone please give me some ideas and suggestions here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do en masse searches against existing full text indexed columns in SQL 2008 by joining onto the `sys.dm_fts_index_keywords` and `sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document` [table valued functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721269%28SQL.100%29.aspx)

For transient data you could look into using the `sys.dm_fts_parser`. Example usage in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447815/sql-server-how-to-compare-two-tables/3450807#3450807) to a similar question.